# object doesn't support this property or method vba

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone tell me why these lines:

```
Sheets("Order").Cells(orderNum, 1).Value = box.Object.Caption
Sheets("Order").Cells(orderNum, 2).Value = box.Object.GroupName
```

are causing the error "Object doesn't support this property or method"? They seem very straightforward to me.

Here's more of the code:

```
For Each box In OLEObjects

box.Object.BackColor = RGB(220, 230, 241)

CommandButton1.BackColor = RGB(240, 240, 240)
CommandButton2.BackColor = RGB(240, 240, 240)

TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
TextBox2.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)

'There is a very long If statement here that I'm fairly certain isn't relevant

Sheets("Order").Cells(orderNum, 1).Value = box.Object.Caption
Sheets("Order").Cells(orderNum, 2).Value = box.Object.GroupName

orderNum = orderNum + 1

Next
```

Comment: What is orderNum at 1st cycle 0?  Immediate check box.object.caption value

Comment: orderNum = 1 to start

Comment: They'e all different, but in my If statement I assign the values to cells the same ay and there are no issues. No special characters, all very simple like "Battery Requirements" "Features"

Comment: Try seeing what they type of the .caption is, try passing it into a string then passing the string value into the cell.

Comment: Is it possible there are OLE objects on the sheets that don't support Caption / GroupName? You're looping all OLEObjects but not testing the type...